# Boto3 Paginator for describe_volumes

Tags: boto3

Below works as expected

```
import boto3
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_PROFILE = "xxx"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
client = session.client('ec2',region_name=AWS_REGION)
response = client.describe_volumes()
volumeIds = []
for i in response['Volumes']:
  volumeIds.append(i['VolumeId'])
  deltag = client.delete_tags(
      Resources=volumeIds,
      Tags=[{'Key': 'app'}]
      )
```

Now trying to add paginator, so tried below.

```
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_PROFILE = "xxx"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
client = session.client('ec2',region_name=AWS_REGION)
pag = client.get_paginator('describe_volumes')
volumeIds = []
for i in pag['Volumes']:
  volumeIds.append(i['VolumeId'])
  deltag = client.delete_tags(
      Resources=volumeIds,
      Tags=[{'Key': 'app'}]
      )



Error i got is
```

TypeError: 'EC2.Paginator.DescribeVolumes' object is not subscriptable

Any suggestions pls ? thanks

Comment: `for page in pag: i = page['Volumes']`

Comment: i tried it no luck, pls give full code

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a page iterator from the paginator object.

```py
page_iterator = pag.paginate()
```

Then, loop through the results from the page iterator. On each page, you need to get a list of the volumes, and add each of the volumes into the larger list.

```
for page in page_iterator:
    volumes = page['Volumes']
    for volume in volumes:
        volumeIds.append(volume['VolumeId'])
```

Once all the `VolumeId`s are collected, then you can run your delete command, outside the loop.

```py
client.delete_tags(
    Resources=volumeIds,
    Tags=[{'Key': 'app'}]
)
```

Sources: [Paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html), [`ec2.Client.describe_volumes`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_volumes)